# Linq return WhereEnumerableIterator from Dictionary value matches?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following code to return items from  `Dictionary<int, string> buttonGroups`
where the values match certain string.

```
    public static void RemoveColorRange(List<Button> buttons, int[] matches)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> buttonGroups = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (Button btn in buttons)
        {                               
            if ((int)btn.Tag == matches[0] || (int)btn.Tag == matches[1])
                continue;

            SolidColorBrush brush = (SolidColorBrush)btn.Background;
            Color color = new Color();
            color = brush.Color;
            buttonGroups.Add((int)btn.Tag, closestColor(color));               
        }

        var buttonMatches = buttonGroups.Where(x => x.Value == 'somestring');
    }
```

However it returns the following type instead of a dictionary object. I can't seem to retrieve any value from buttonMatches. What am I missing?

```
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,string>>}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `Where` does not return a dictionary. To have a dictionary you need to explicitly covert result of filtering to one:

```
var buttonMatches = buttonGroups.Where(x => x.Value == 'somestring')
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Or you should just do the checking before adding to the dictionary.